# Routing Private Networks over VPN

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, vpn, routing

I have a private network in my workplace that I would like to connect to through my laptop.
The network 192.168.26.0 is added to my office desktop through an IP Alias.
I am connecting from my laptop to my office desktop through VPN.
Is there a way to access the network 192.168.26.0 using this VPN connection?

laptop <-- VPN --> (office + 192.168.26.0)

I am using ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: usually the VPN server will be configured to push routes to VPN clients, so is your server pushing a route for 192.168.26.0/24? you should see it if you run `route`

Comment: I do not own the VPN server. I am just an end user.  Can I route through my office desktop because the .26.0 network is connected to my desktop?